# How do I use GDB Debugger to look at __asm__ content?

Tags: c, assembly, debugging

I'm trying to understand what is happening in this code, specifically within `__asm__`. How do I step through the assembly code, so I can print each variable and what not?

Specifically, I am trying to step through this to figure out what does the `8()` mean and to see how does it know that it is going into array at index 2.

```
 /* a[2] = 99 in assembly */
  __asm__("\n\
     movl $_a, %eax\n\
     movl $99, 8(%eax)\n\
");
```

Comment: The keyword you need in gdb is `disassemble`... :_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movl $_a, %eax      // load the memory address of a into %eax

movl $99, 8(%eax)   // jump 8 bytes and store number 99 (which is a[2])
```

It seems to me that `a` is an *int* array (*int* has 4 bytes in most platforms). So by increment 4 bytes you'll be accessing the next item of the array. Other examples of assigning values to this array would be:

```
movl $10, (%eax)   // store number 10 on the the first position: a[0]

movl $20, 4(%eax)  // jump 4 bytes from the address loaded in %eax 
                   // and store number 20 on the next position (a[1])
```

Comment: For future reference, how can I figure out how much bytes are in an element of an array? What if it was a string? What if I was on another system? etc... I'm guessing I'll have to look at documentation, but things like this seems really hard to dig up on the internet.

Comment: You must read: Programming from the Ground Up. It's a free book available on the web and it's awesome: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The `stepi` command steps through the assembly one instruction at a time.  There is also a `nexti` for stepping over function calls.  These commands do not adhere to the 'type only the unique prefix of a command is enough' rule that works for most commands -- partially because they the `next` and `step` commands are entirely prefixes of these commands and partially because these are not used too often and when they are they are typically used by someone who knows that they really want to use them.

`info registers` displays a lot of the register contents.

You'll also want to view the disassembly with the `disassemble` command.

More info on all of these commands is available with the `help` command, for instance:

```
(gdb) help info registers
```

tells you that `info registers` displays the integer registers and their contents, but it also tells you that if you supply a register name it will limit output to that register's value:

```
(gdb) info registers rax
rax            0x0  0
```

(`rax` is the x86_64 version of `eax`)
The first column is the register name, the second is the hex value, and the third is the integer value.

There is useful `help` for the `disassemble` command as well.

Remember that gdb has tab completion for many commands, and this can be used for more than just simple commands, though many times it offers you bad suggestions -- it's sometimes helpful, though.

Including a label within your inline assembly will allow you to easily make a break point at the beginning of it.

Comment: I thought `ni` would step through the `__asm__` too, so I set a break point at `__asm__` line and then typed `ni`, and it stepped through all the assembly. Was i doing something wrong?

Comment: When you said "stepped through all" do you mean that it single stepped for each assembly instruction?  I thought that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I was never any good at AT&T syntax, but I'm pretty sure the `8(%eax)` part means "the address 8 bytes after the address stored in EAX", that is, it's the offset relative to the address stored in the register.

Approximate equivalent in Intel syntax would be something like this (off the top of my head, so it's entirely possible that there is some minor mistake here...)

```
mov eax, a
mov DWORD PTR [eax+8], 99
```

Comment: it'd actually be `mov DWORD PTR [eax+8], 99` I believe, but yeah.

Comment: @caf: Yes, you're absolutely right. That's what I get for answering questions at 4 in the morning...